# Homeomorphism from A to Cl(A)

Tags: general-topology

I've been working through various old topology books, asking myself questions and have managed to get myself stuck. I am currently trying to prove the following:

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space and $A$ a subset of $X$. Let $h:A \rightarrow Cl(A)$ be a homeomorphism. If $(x_{n})$ is a sequence in $A$ that converges to some $L \in X$. Then $h(x_{n})$ converges.

It seems intuitively true to me but when trying to prove the trouble is $h(L)$ is not always defined. Any proof would be appreciated.

Comment: Consider the Euclidean space with the usual topology. If you consider $A=(0,1)$ then $\mathrm{Cl}(A)=[0,1].$ Now, they are not homeomorphic: $A$ is not compact and its closure is compact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result is false as stated, even if $h$ is supposed to be surjective.

Let $X=[0,2)$ with the usual topology, and let $A=(0,2)$. For $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $x_n=\frac1n$; clearly $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ is a sequence in $A$ converging in $X$ to $L=0$. Let

$$h:(0,2)\to[0,2):x\mapsto 2-x\;;$$

then $h$ is a homeomorphism from $A$ to $\operatorname{cl}A=X$, and $\langle h(x_n):n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ does not converge.

If $h$ is surjective, so that $A$ is actually homeomorphic to its closure, we have to work harder. Let $X=\Bbb Q$ with its usual topology, and let $A$ be any dense subset of $\Bbb Q$ whose complement is also dense. Then $A$ is a countable metric space with no isolated points, so it’s homeomorphic to $\Bbb Q$, which is of course its closure. Fix $q\in\Bbb Q\setminus A$, and let $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ be a sequence in $A$ converging to $q$. Let $\alpha$ be any irrational number, e.g., $\sqrt2$. Then $\{p\in\Bbb Q:p<\alpha\}$ is homeomorphic to $\{x\in A:x<q\}$, and $\{p\in\Bbb Q:p>\alpha\}$ is homeomorphic to $\{x\in A:x>q\}$. Let

$$h_0:\{x\in A:x<q\}\to\{p\in\Bbb Q:p<\alpha\}$$

and

$$h_1:\{x\in A:x>q\}\to\{p\in\Bbb Q:p>\alpha\}$$

be surjective homeomorphisms. The domains of $h_0$ and $h_1$ are clopen in $A$, and their ranges are clopen in $\Bbb Q$, so

$$h=h_0\cup h_1:A\to\Bbb Q\mapsto\begin{cases}
h_0(x),&\text{if }x<q\\
h_1(x),&\text{if }x>q
\end{cases}$$

is a homeomorphism of $A$ onto $\Bbb Q=\operatorname{cl}A$. However, $\langle h(x_n):n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ does not converge: in $\Bbb R$ it converges to $\alpha$, but $\alpha\notin\Bbb Q$.

Comment: This is a very well constructed counterexample to the stated problem. I was intending A to be an uncountable subset of X, I didn't state it explicitly that way because I hadn't really been considering countable subsets at all. Then again I couldn't see the jump from countable to uncountable making the conjecture any more true.